# Close pretty photo slideshow on click of last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, prettyphoto

I am using pretty photo jquery plugin to display slide show, last slide is 'Enter site', when user click on this slide, slide show should stop and user will be redirected to home page of website. How can I implement this.

I tried to use onclick event of  and  tag but none of them are getting called. I even tried to register onclick event from jQuery using 'on' function but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using a callback function?

Comment: Can you add a bit of code to see what you have now?

Comment: @Alessio I tried that but problem is how to close the slide show when last slide is clicked.

Comment: @dingo_d You can see here http://beadvendors.com/

Answer (score 0):

Since the callback function is called when prettyPhoto is closed, you need to use:
***changepicturecallback***, which is called everytime an item is shown/changed.
In this function you have to read the current item and evaluate if it's the last one.

Try this piece of code:

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
  animationSpeed:'normal',
  slideshow:5000,
  show_title: true,
  allow_resize: true,
  autoplay_slideshow: true,
  social_tools: false,
  deeplinking: false,
  callback: function(){
      console.log('pretty photo is closed')
  },
  image_markup: '<img id="fullResImage" class="fullResImage" src="{path}" />',
  changepicturecallback: function(){
      var currentSlide = ($('.pp_gallery').find('li').index($('.selected'))+1);
      var myArray = jQuery('.currentTextHolder').text().split('/');
      if(currentSlide == myArray[1]){
        /* Make redirect to your HP */
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: I need not to close the slide show when particular slide comes, I need to close it when use click on last slide which is 'Enter Site'